# Estimate Expected Value of Ratio of Random Variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

I found this question in Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis's chapter on Asymptotics.

Assume you have two independent random variables $X$ (with mean 4 and standard deviation 1) and $Y$ (with mean 3 and standard deviation 2). How do you approximate the mean and standard deviation of $Y/X$? Under what assumptions is the approximation reasonable?

I tried to approximate these random variables as Normal with sample size large enough, but this requires calculating $E(Z^{-1})$ and other negative moments of a Normal distribution, and I think these integrals don't converge.

Comment: If you either have $P(X=0)\gt 0$ or have a density with $f(0)\gt 0$ (such as normal distribution) then you will not have a finite mean for $1/X$ and therefore for $Y/X$

Comment: Could you please provide more specific indication of the source. I search the whole book and did not find anything close to this question.

Comment: @NCh this is from the exercises in Chapter 4 - in the third edition it's Question 5

Comment: Thank you, i found it. I previously looked at second edition. Very intriguing and mysterious exercise.